# Input string was not in a correct format. Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
    {
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        row.Cells[1].Text = "ACCEPTED";
        string msg = "ACCEPTED";
        Session["c_email"] = row.Cells[4].Text;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        string insert = "insert into Status values(@email,@c_email,@status)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_email", Session["c_email"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session["mechanic"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", msg.ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label1.Text = "You need to reach the customer within one hour and provide the needful service.";
        con.Close();
    }
```

I have been trying to solve this error but couldn't do so. The string is not in correct format, this error is popping. But what could be the solution? I have tried a several ways like "int.Parse", "Int32.TryParse" and also I added e.CommandArgument.ToString()
But all was just of no use. Please help me out with this error.
Thanking you with anticipation.

[image: This is the error]

.aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
     OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  
     CssClass="table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table"  
     BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" CellPadding="3"  
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnpreview" runat="server" Text="Accept" CommandName="Accept" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnselect" runat="server" Text="Reject" CommandName="Reject" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="First name" SortExpression="first_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="Last name" SortExpression="last_name" />
```

Comment: Please share your aspx code as well for the button which is firing "Accept" command!

Comment: Clearly you need to provide string in *correct format*. We have no idea what current value is so there is absolutely nothing can be suggested outside that.

Comment: When debugging, what is value of e.CommandArgument ?

Comment: What's `e.CommandArgument` value? Probably it's not convertible to int, like `3.0` or `text`

Comment: So looking at your aspx code, you are not passing any CommandArgument `<asp:Button ID="btnpreview" runat="server" Text="Accept" CommandName="Accept" CommandArgument="?" />`

Comment: e.CommandArgument value is empty  ""

Comment: what should be the argument sir?

Comment: @TazimShaikh do you want to pass some numeric column value from the `SqlDataSource1` datasource bound to your GridView?

Comment: What do you expect it to be -- clearly you think it will index something?

Comment: My concept is to fetch value when the accept button is clicked from the respected row.

Comment: @TazimShaikh which value you want to fetch when the button is clicked?

Comment: Try using `CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>'`

Comment: the firstname of bound field

Comment: Thank you so much Kamalpreet sir and all other sirs who have helped me. The error is solved. by using CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Accept button to-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnpreview" runat="server" Text="Accept" CommandName="Accept" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>' />
```

Note `CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>'` in above line, this will give you index of row.

OR

You can change your code behind to-

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);    
int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
```